# Cant get button to appear

Tags: android, qt, qml

I'm trying to make some sort of fotboll app for android. The problem i'm facing right now, is that I need to make a button in the corner of the screen, (4 different) which you move the game character with. But I've made 1 button now, for moving up, but it doesnt appear on the screen.

Main file:

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Window 2.1

Item {

    id:root

    width:Screen.width
    height:Screen.height-10
    focus:true

    Keys.onPressed: {

        if(event.key===Qt.Key_Up)
        {
            event.accepted = true;
            player.y=(player.y) - 40

        }
        if(event.Key === Qt.Key_Down){
            event.accepted = true;
            player.y = (player.y)+ 40
           }
        if (event.key === Qt.Key_Right)
         { event.accepted=true;
            player.x=(player.x)+40

        }
   if (event.key === Qt.Key_Left)
{event.accepted = true;
       player.x=(player.x) -40
   }

    }

Flickable {
    width:Screen.width
    height:Screen.height
    contentHeight: Screen.height*2
    contentWidth:Screen.width
    interactive:true
    boundsBehavior: Flickable.StopAtBounds
    contentY: Math.min(contentHeight-height, Math.max(0, player.y-height/2))
    contentX: Math.min(contentWidth-width, Math.max(0, player.x-width/2))
    Image{
        id: feild
        anchors.fill:parent
        source:"Namnlös.png"
        sourceSize.height:Screen.height*2
        sourceSize.width:Screen.width
        }

    Image {
        id: player
        source:"asd.png"
        x:Screen.width/2
        y:Screen.height/2
    }
}

}
```

Button file:

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Window 2.1


Rectangle {
    id: simplebutton
    color: "grey"
    width: 100; height: 50

    Text {
      id: buttonLabel
      anchors.centerIn: parent
      text: "Up"
    }

    MouseArea {
        id: buttonMouseArea
        anchors.fill: parent
        onClicked: console.log(buttonLabel.text + "clicked" )

    }
}


Rectangle {
    id: button
    property color buttonColor: "lightblue"
    property color onHoverColor: "gold"
    property color borderColor: "white"

    signal buttonClick()
    onButtonClick: {
        console.log(buttonLabel.text + " clicked" )

    }
    MouseArea {
        onClicked: buttonClick()
        hoverEnabled: true
        onEntered: parent.border.color = onHoverColor
        onExited: parent.border.color = borderColor
    }
    color: buttonMouseArea.pressed ? Qt.darker(buttonColor, 1.5) : buttonColor
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

1) You need to add your button to your layout! Since there you don't add your button into your main file, it won't appear.

2) You need to split your Button file into two separate qml file, since you can only have one "root" item per file.

Comment: Thanks! Once I get home I'll try it out. Thanks for the help :)